# NOT NULL constraint failed: products_product.vendor_id

Tags: django, djangorestframework

estoy teniendo este problema con una foreign key de un modelo. Vi en varias preguntas del mismo tema que con poner 'null=True' ya estaba, pero en mi caso necesito que sea obligatorio el campo, ademas probe usar null=True pero cuando hago un post queda el campo en null, sin importar lo que cargue.

views.py:

```
        def create(self, request):
            
            # Solve true != True error  
            condetalle = request.data.get('condetalle', False)
            if condetalle == 'true':
                condetalle = True
            
            new_prod = models.Product.objects.create(
                name = request.data['name'],
                price = request.data['price'],
                quantity = request.data['quantity'],
                condetalle = condetalle,
                art_base = request.data['art_base']
            )   
                
            new_prod.save()
            serializer = serializers.ProductSerializer(new_prod)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

models.py

```
# Create your models here.
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    condetalle = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    art_base = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

[image: NOT NULL constraint failed error]

Comment: Al final pude encontrar el problema. En el views.py no agregue el campo en el metodo create. El problema es que ahora me esta tirando un error "Cannot assign "'1'": "Product.vendor" must be a "Vendor" instance."

Answer (score 0):

El problema estaba en que no agregue el campo de vendor en el metodo create.
Agrego como quedaria resuelto

```
new_prod = models.Product.objects.create(
            name = request.data['name'],
            price = request.data['price'],
            quantity = request.data['quantity'],
            condetalle = condetalle,
            art_base = request.data['art_base'],
            vendor = Vendor.objects.get(id=request.data['vendor'])
        )
```